# Why not: Multiple Steps in the Direction of One Gradient

Tags: gradient-descent, neural-networks

In gradient descent, we calculate the negative gradient of a function and change our inputs in this direction. This is repeated until the gradient becomes very small, meaning that we are close to a local minimum.

How far we move in the direction of the negative gradient is determined by the **step size**, which is a parameter that is important to choose well.

In cases where calculating the gradient is expensive, but evaluation is not:

Does it make sense to move **several steps into the same direction of a calculated gradient**, until the output starts increasing?

At this point we can go back (half?) a step and calculate the next gradient / propagate the $stepsnumber * stepsize * gradient$ backwards.

This would assume taking a relatively *small step size*.

Possible reasons that sound plausible are:

- It is already done successfully.
- Computing the forward pass is not cheaper than re-evaluating the gradient.
- There is some incompatibility with backpropagation. Reason?
- In high dimensions, something subtle happens.
- Some other practical consideration.

If it is one of those, please explain what exactly happens.

I am mainly interested in applications in neural networks, and if a method like this is being used there, or if there are reasons not to.

Comment: Yes this can be done. For example *line search methods* can use this approach. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to take several steps without re-evaluating the gradient?  So wouldn't that just be the same idea as simply taking one larger step? So maybe what you want is to be able to change the step size based on what seems to happen locally? (e.g. if, on the basis of the last few steps, the slope seems pretty smooth and constant, take some larger steps, but if it seems more rough and fluctuating, take smaller steps)

Comment: @Bram28 The number of the little steps would not be fixed, but dependant on the result of the step. Taking a too big step can result in going too far, missing the minimum. But if we check how low we are at each point in between, we can realize at what point we move upwards again, and make the overall step exactly until there.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. And then yes, what you're suggesting sounds very reasonable ... and going by other comments and answer, already implemented. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, what you're suggesting is essentially called [line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search) (see also [backtracking line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search)). I suspect that line search is not ubiquitous in machine learning because stochastic descent methods (which take one step per individual training datum per epoch) have better generalization performance and it'd be counterproductive to spend time doing a line search on each one of those single-datum steps; it'd be time spent pointlessly "fine tuning a heuristic." (Note another reason why single-datum or small batch steps are preferred is because large batches like the full data set are often too large to practically work on all at once).

Comment: Related discussion: [Why aren't line search algorithms used in optimizing neural networks?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4trmky/why_arent_line_search_algorithms_used_in/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can for example make a line search (Golden ratio or Fibonacci) in the direction of the negative gradient (bisection also works like you said). There are also more advanced methods like: Powell's method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think line search is about the idea that I'm thinking of. As I see it, it is not used a lot in optimization, especially in the context of neural networks. I'm primarily interested why not, or if it would be a good idea to incorporate something like line search. I will clarify the question in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should look into applying adaptive learning rate in your neural net training algorithm.  This would achieve the accelerated learning you want and is pretty common.  You could also look into momentum which will speed up training and avoid getting trapped in local optima, and is also a commonly used approach.